# Python create tuple of arrays' zip from variable length dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, tuples

the title might be overly complicated.

What I am try to do is the following :

Given a dictionary of arrays

`h = {'full':[10, 8, 6, 4, 2],'train':[12, 10, 8, 6, 4],'test':[8,6,4,2, 0]}`

I'd like to get a tuple of all the elements of the arrays where the first element is taken from the first element of the first array, the second from the first element of the second array, the third from the first element of the third array, the fourth is the second element of the first array, and so on till exhaustion.

If I knew the number of arrays was always 3 I could do :

```
sets = list(h.keys())
t = sum( zip( h[sets[0], h[sets[1]], h[sets[2]] ), () )
```

This yields `(10, 12, 8, 8, 10, 6, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 4, 0)`.

Not knowing how many keys there are in the dictionary I've tried :

```
t = sum( zip( [ h[k] for k in h.keys() ] ), () )
```

But this yields :
`([10, 8, 6, 4, 2], [12, 10, 8, 6, 4], [8, 6, 4, 2, 0])`

Any idea on how to get the result above with a variable length dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could flatten the unpacked zipped triplets from `zip(*h.values())`:

```
>>> h = {'full':[10, 8, 6, 4, 2],'train':[12, 10, 8, 6, 4],'test':[8,6,4,2, 0]}
>>> tuple(zip(*h.values()))
((10, 12, 8), (8, 10, 6), (6, 8, 4), (4, 6, 2), (2, 4, 0))
>>> tuple(x for y in zip(*h.values()) for x in y)
(10, 12, 8, 8, 10, 6, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 2, 2, 4, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One small modification to your code can do what you need:

```
t = sum( zip( *[ h[k] for k in h.keys() ] ), () )
```

The `*` is used to unpack a list in python.

For example:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*x)
1 2 3
>>> print(x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it works or point to an external resource that dose?Not sure what the * is meant to do!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can first `zip` the values of your dict. `zip` accepts any number of iterables, so we unpack the `h.values()` to provide them.

Then, we just have to [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the zipped values.

```
from itertools import chain

h = {'full':  [11, 18, 16, 14, 12],
     'train': [22, 20, 28, 26, 24],
     'test':  [38, 36, 34, 32, 30]}

out = tuple(chain.from_iterable(zip(*h.values())))

print(out)
# (11, 22, 38, 18, 20, 36, 16, 28, 34, 14, 26, 32, 12, 24, 30)
```